# scrapy run order, prints before it's assigned

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

so the problem is the run order, it basically runs the fuctions last

```
import scrapy

class uppspider(scrapy.Spider):
      start_urls = ['something.com']
      def parse(self, response):
          return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
              response,
              formdata={'login': '', 'Password': ''},
              callback=self.after_login
          )

      def after_login(self, response):
            #check login succeed before going on

          return Request(url="", callback=self.ret)

      def ret(self, response):
            #scraping
              yield scrapy.Request(callback=self.parse_tastypage)


      def parse_tastypage(self, response):

            item = uppItem()
            er = response.status      
            self = list()
            self.append(er)

            #scraping

             yield item

      print "whatever i print here, prints before the spider"

      mylist = list()
      parse_tastypage(mylist, 0)
      print (mylist)
```

so if i want to print a variable assigned in a function. It doesn't work because it gets printed before assigned in function.

Comment: @Umair i basically want to print a varible(er) assigned in the last function outside of that funcktion

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging 

class uppspider(scrapy.Spider):
    mylist = list()

    def parse_tastypage(self):
        # access the above declared list like this
        self.mylist = ['some data']

    parse_tastypage()

    logging.info(mylist) # this will print ['some data']
```

Comment: it doesn't work this parse_tastypage(self): should be def parse_tastypage(self, response): and parse_tastypage() need to have two arguments.

Comment: Ok then you can change it

Comment: but you didn't do anything. you just write what i alredy written

Comment: Bro look at "self" i added that. Thats the way u can access class variables inside of a function